# Add column dynamically to the right of the table but need to add as a merged column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Need to add a column via JavaScript to the right side of the existing table. But it should be rawspanned. I mean it has only one cell in the tbody section. Can someone help with this? I attached an image to understand. thanks.Also wanted to know how to add a button inside this newly added column as well.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJAzE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')

document.querySelector('#bt-add').onclick = () =>
  {
  myTable.tHead.rows[0].insertCell()
  myTable.tBodies[0].rows[0].insertCell().setAttribute('rowspan', myTable.rows.length -1)
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding : .2em .8em;
  border  : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color : lightsteelblue;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a3</td><td>b3</td><td>c3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="bt-add">add 1 column</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you teach me how to add a button inside this newly added column as well? Via JavaScript?